# Instantiation of WCF service client throws exception regarding IsOneWay operations

Tags: .net, wcf, runtime-error

I have two WCF services hosted in IIS running on a server; Ogre (C#) and Troll (VB.Net). (Yes, that is their real names.)  In this process I call a web method in the Troll service.  The Troll in turn calls the Ogre for a supporting function.

When the Troll attempts to instantiate the Ogre service client:

```
Dim ogre As New OgreService.OgreClient
```

an exception is thrown.  That exception is

```
Operations marked with IsOneWay=true must not declare output parameters, by-reference parameters or return values.
```

Now, the ogre does have a few methods defined as one way.  However, they all return void and none have output parameters.  Some do accept an object (defined in the data contract) as a parameter.  There are several other programs that call the ogre without a problem.  Furthermore, if I run the Troll on my development system, in Visual Studio, it *does not* have a problem calling the ogre on the server. I can also call the ogre on the server from my development machine, using the WCF Test Client, and have no problems.

I know that this has got to be a configuration issue but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.  Are there any issues with an IIS hosted WCF service calling another IIS hosted WCF service on the same machine?

I'm not even sure what data I can provide that might be of help as it is only the one configuration that is experiencing the problem.  Any ideas of what might be going on would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

It turns out that this is a problem with the service proxy that Visual Studio generated.  When I configured the service reference I accidently checked the "Allow generation of asynchronous operations".  The option to generate task-based operations was selected.

This caused methods to be defined with the one-way decoration that returned a value.

So that is what caused the problem.  Since I don't need asynchronous operations I just unchecked that option and the problem went away.

It does bring up other questions such as "Why didn't it fail when running from my development machine?" and "Why does the automatically generated client generate code that is not valid?" but that is for another discussion.

Comment: Are they hosted in the same AppPool ( assuming IIS 6 n above)?

Comment: No, they are not.  However, I discovered the problem which I will post here in a few minutes.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh cool ... But somewhere I feel the issue should be in wsdl , because synchronous or asynchronous , when you have kept them one way it shoudln't have errored out ... and sometimes we need to manually update the service reference .. but interesting topic

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue and here's what worked for me. Everything works fine on the dev box but the exception regarding IsOneWay is on the deployment env. Upgrading 4.5.1 of the .Net framework on the the deployment environment fixed it.